# NoReverseMatch - not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I was working at my first project, but I got:

> NoReverseMatch with Exception Value: 'hiring_log_app' is not a
>   registered namespace in base.html

which follows:

```
href="{% url 'hiring_log_app:index' %}" >Hiring Log

href="{% url 'hiring_log_app:topics' %}" >Topics
```

I made sure my namespace was correct and I looked at the other topics already opened without figuring out how to solve the issue.

I paste urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include ('hiring_log_app.urls', namespace='hiring_log_app')),
```

hiring_log_app/urls.py:

```
"""Define URL patterns for hiring_log_app"""
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^topics/$', views.topics, name='topics'),
              ]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render    
from .models import Topic

def index(request):
    """The home page for hiring_log_app"""
    return render(request, 'hiring_log_app/index.html') 

def topics(request):
    """ list of topics"""
    topics = Topic.objects.raw( "SELECT text FROM HIRING_LOG_APP_TOPIC;")                                  
    context = {'topics' : topics}
    return render(request, 'hiring_log_app/topics.html', context)
```

Does anyone know where I am making a mistake?

Comment: Can you please try to fix your formatting?

Comment: add app_name = 'hiring_log_app' in hiring_log_app/urls.py: and mention version of django

Comment: First of all thank you for your kind reply....I've followed this suggestion but still I get the same error claming that 'hiring_log_app' is not a registered namespace. The django version is 2.2.4....I may attach the traceback returned by browser if it may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrongly specified the namespace in **urlpatterns**. Follow the pattern below:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include, url
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include (('hiring_log_app.urls','hiring_log_app'), namespace='hiring_log_app'))
```

**Edit:**

If you are using Django 2.2.4 then you should use **path** instead of *url* since the usage of it is replaced by `re_path`.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include    
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    re_path(r'', include (('hiring_log_app.urls','hiring_log_app'), namespace='hiring_log_app'))
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your kind reply....I've followed the above suggestion but still I get the same error claming that 'hiring_log_app' is not a registered namespace. The django version is 2.2.4 may it change something? I may also attach the traceback if it can be useful.